# How to show double figure number in calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar

This is my code which display date in like this format 15 8 2013  but I want to display it in double figure if month or date is single figure if day is 8 is should display 08 if month is 8 it should be displayed as 08.  I don't want to add 9 times if  condition for month and date is there any fast method or for loop which detect single character fount then add 0 ?

```
like if (mday=1) {
         mday=01
     }

     if (mday=2) {
          mday=02
     }

     if (mMonth=2) {
          mMonth =02
     }

     if (mMonth=2) {
          mMonth =02
     }

int completedate2;

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

     Toast.makeText(this, "current date is" +mDay+mMonth+mYear, 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     completedate2=mDay+mMonth+mYear;
```

Comment: i want to display date if is below 10 then shoe like this 01 ,02, 03,04etc  same for month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.format("%02d", mday)
```

Should format the number into 2 digits for you, with a leading 0 if its a single digit.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "current date is" +String.format("%02d", mday)+String.format("%02d", mMonth)+mYear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

EDIT:

```
 String completedate2 = String.format("%02d", mday) + String.format("%02d", mMonth) + mYear;
```

Comment: how i will add in this string   completedate2=mDay+mMonth+mYear;

Comment: i did like this  completedate2= String.format("%02d", mDay)+    String.format("%02d", mMonth)   +mYear;  and is work thnx:0

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
String date=(mday<10?"0" + mday:mday) + (mMonth<10?"0" + mMonth:mMonth) + mYear;
```

It checks if the value is lower than 10 and then add 0 at the start.

Comment: thsi show error  The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>, java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>

Comment: I am using ?: operation. You can clear the error I think. In my project no such error. Anyway, the other answer is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the built-in formatters. Consider:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Toast.makeText(this, "current date is"
 + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").format(mCalendar.getTime())).show();
```

Note that java.text.Format objects are not thread safe.